# Unexpected behavior of DiscretizeGraphics

Tags: built-in-symbols, discretization

As this code,we can visualize the "Test text"

```
Graphics[Text[Style["Test text",20],{0,0}],Axes->True,AxesOrigin->{0,0}]
```

[image]

I try to use `DiscretizeGraphics` to get the width and length of "Test text".

```
Abs[Subtract@@@RegionBounds[DiscretizeGraphics[Text[Style["Test text",20],{0,0}],_Text]]]
```

> {75.6577,8.49565}

The result is unexpected obviously.

## Question

1. Is this a bug of `DiscretizeGraphics`?
2. Can any solution get the width and length of "Test text"?

Comment: Isn't the problem that the RegionBounds aren't set? If you inscribe the text in a `Circle[{0, 0}, {i, j}],` within the same `Graphics[]`, the text doesn't change in size if you change the radii of the circle.

Comment: @Feyre I think this isn't the problem of `RegionBounds`,If your click <kbd>.</kbd> then move your cusor to right bottom of the "Test text",you can see the coordinate [like this](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-07-01-20-06-11.png).

Comment: But those are the bounds of the meshregion you've created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Text` does not scale with the `ImageSize`.  Try to manually resize graphics containing text (by dragging the handle).  The text will not change size.  Text size is given in [absolute units](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Offset.html).

To get the dimension of text in absolute units (which is distinct from the Graphics coordinate system), use `Rasterize[..., "RasterSize"]`.  If you use `"BoundingBox"` instead of `"RasterSize"`, it will also give you the baseline position.